# wrong number of decimal display with MS-SQL decimal field in ruby on rails

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm working on an RoR project with MS SQL 2005 database.
In the database, I have a table named "equipments", where I have a field named "std_unit", defined as a data type decimal(18,2).

A strange behavior is that even I store a value in that field 2-decimal-place ok, however, it displays too many decimal digits after the decimal point as a result of my ruby code.
The following example shows how it looks like when stored in there, I looked it up through SQL Management Studio.

```
    e.g (how it looks when stored in the database)

        std_unit
        ========
        11.11

schema definition in Rails 

        schema.rb
        ----------
        t.decimal  "std_unit",      :precision => 18, :scale => 2
```

when I extract the data off to present in a Rails view, what I got is the same figure
with too many digits after the decimal point.

```
Then I retrieve that value via the following line of code thru active_record.

eq.std_unit

standard unit   11.1099853515625
```

any thing might be wrong with my configuration? and how to get rid of that?

any advice would be very much appreciated.